# Creating a Google Adsense AdUnit with the Python API?

Tags: python, adsense, adsense-api

How do you use the Python [Adsense Management API](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/reference/rest/v2/accounts.adclients.adunits/create) to create adunits?

Based on documentation and some examples I've found, it should be something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
pip install google-auth google-auth-oauthlib google-auth-httplib2
"""

from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

account_id = 'pub-<id>'

ad_client_id = 'ca-pub-<id>'

# Load credentials from the downloaded JSON file
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('myservicekey.json', scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adsense'])

# Create AdSense API service
adsense_service = build('adsense', 'v2', credentials=credentials)

# Define the ad client data
ad_client_data = {
    "productCode": "AFC",
    "supportsReporting": True,
    "kind": "adsense#adClient",
}

# Define the ad unit data
ad_unit_data = {
    "contentAdsSettings": {
        "backupOption": {
            "type": "USE_DEFAULT"
        },
        "size": "SIZE_UNSPECIFIED"
    },
    "name": "Test Ad 123",
    "customStyle": {
        "colors": {
            "border": "#ffffff",
            "title": "#333333",
            "background": "#ffffff",
            "text": "#666666",
            "url": "#1a0dab"
        }
    },
    "mobileContentAdsSettings": {
        "size": "SIZE_UNSPECIFIED"
    },
    "settings": {
        "size": ["SIZE_UNSPECIFIED"]
    }
}

# Create the ad unit, none of these work.
# ad_unit = adsense_service.accounts().adunits().create(body=ad_unit_data, parent=ad_client['name']).execute()
# ad_unit = adsense_service.accounts().adunits().create(body=ad_unit_data, parent=f'accounts/{account_id}/adclients/{ad_client_id}').execute()
# ad_unit = adsense_service.accounts().adclients().adunits().create(body=ad_unit_data, parent=f'accounts/{account_id}/adclients/{ad_client_id}').execute()
# ad_unit = adsense_service.accounts().adunits().insert(body=ad_unit_data, accountId=account_id, adClientId=ad_client_id).execute()
ad_unit = adsense_service.accounts().adclients().adunits().create(body=ad_unit_data, parent=f'accounts/{account_id}/adclients/{ad_client_id}').execute()
```

However, all variations of the final call to create `ad_unit` fail with the error `AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'create'` or `AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'insert'` if I try to use the older `insert()` method.

My call appears to correctly follow the `accounts.adclients.adunits.create` path listed in the v2 docs.

What am I doing wrong? Why is the `create()` method missing?